# Conversions between ecore and OWL

Tags: semantic-web, owl, eclipse-emf-ecore

For a new project we are attempting to convert some models that were done in the Eclipse EMF framework and are stored in ecore format to OWL 2 models.

Much of the searches referred to this site: http://perso.univ-lr.fr/ghillair/projects.html which contains two downloadable zip files; one to convert ecore to OWL and one to go in the other direction.  They are done in the ATL transformation language.

I've tried to run these in Eclipse, but it appears they were built for ATL 2 and they don't play nice with ATL 3.  I tried to install ATL 2, but that doesn't work with the version of Eclipse my firm uses.  The ATL documentation itself is not very helpful nor are the error messages it generates when things go wrong.

One of the problems clearly seems to be changes in the ANT tasks used to run ATL; I tried doing away with these and running the same steps (or so I thought) from the launch feature in Eclipse.  However, even using the sample ecore file provided with the download, this is resulting in a totally empty OWL file.

Has anyone managed to get this working in ATL3?